# Getting from Moscow Sheremetyevo airport to Dubna

Tags: trains, russia, transportation, svo

I need to get from Moscow Sheremetyevo airport to Dubna in evening of 4.7 as late as possible but with arrival to Dubna still before midnight.

I tried to find public transport planners for Russia but I didn't find any which worked and I don't know how much I can trust accuracy of Google maps data for Russia transport (which returns some connections) because I can't verify them against other source.

I'm landing on Sheremetyevo airport by flight from Prague.
But I know from my search that flights Prague-Sheremetyevo are more frequent than transport connection Sheremetyevo-Dubna. So I search for it first.

Which transport connections fits my requirements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest that you travel from the airport to Lobnya or Sheremetyevskaya train station on the Savyolovskoye line. From there, there are [direct trains](http://www.tutu.ru/rasp.php?st1=29804&st2=32004&date=04.07.2015) to Dubna. Lobnya is better because some trains skip Sheremetyevskaya. The trouble with railway timetable is that it is likely to be altered with some trains canceled and some rescheduled, and that needs to be checked a day or two beforehand (use the same link, altered trains will be marked with exclamation signs). Late evening trains are not likely to be affected, though.

Unfortunately, as far as I can see, there is no direct connection between Sheremetyevo-DEF and one of these stations; but there is a [bus #21](http://www.lobnya.ru/content/view/1341/259/) that runs between Sheremetyevo-BC and Lobnya train station.

Actually, SVO-DEF has a train line which is a branch of the Savyolovskoye line, but it is only used for Aeroexpress trains that run non-stop to Belorusskiy train terminal (which is not even the main hub for the Savyolovskoye line and only has one direct train to Dubna in the morning). However, you may try this route: ride an [Aeroexpress](https://aeroexpress.ru/en/sheremetyevo.html) to Belorusskiy, then change to a [train](http://www.tutu.ru/rasp.php?st1=101&st2=28604&date=04.07.2015) to Savyolovskiy, and then change to a [train](http://www.tutu.ru/rasp.php?st1=28604&st2=32004&date=04.07.2015) to Dubna. Savyolovskiy has a few express trains to Dubna which are pleasanter to ride.

Comment: The last option (3 trains) is the most reliable one.
The latest train leaves Savelovsky at 21:55 and arrives at 23:54. If this fits the "before midnight" requirement for OP, he may leave airport on 20:30 aeroexpress train, and then take 21:36 train to Savelovsky.
Otherwise it's 19:30 - 20:05 Aeroexpress, then 20:16 - 20:21 to Savelovsky, then 20:42 - 23:20 to Dubna.

Comment: @IMil, I am not so sure. Of course, trains in Russia are relatively reliable if you take notice of timetable changes. But on the other hand, on a Saturday evening roads are relatively free of traffic, so the chances of getting stuck on a bus or taxi is small.

Comment: Thanks both @IMil and andrey-chernyakhovskiy, all proposed connections fits my needs perfectly. But I just was told by email that summer school, which I will attend in Dubna, started to offer possibility of pickup by minibus on Moscow Airports. I'll use it as direct minibus is much better that connection with couple of transfers.

Comment: This would be the most convenient solution indeed. Just check the price: the train route would cost about 800 roubles, how much will the minibus cost?

Which summer school exactly are you planning to attend, BTW?

Comment: @IMil Travel cost are covered by agreement between my home institution - [Institute of Experimental and Applied Physics of Czech Technical University in Prague](http://www.utef.cvut.cz/en/) and by institution where the school is organized - [Joint Institute for Nuclear Research in Dubna](http://newuc.jinr.ru/). School is called ["2015 Student Practice in JINR Fields of Research (2nd stage)"](http://newuc.jinr.ru/events.asp?id=54&language=eng)

Comment: Yandex.Maps say there's bus 817 that runs from DEF to BC.

Answer (score 0):

I actually recommend taking Uber or other kind of ride hailing service to Lobnya railway station. And there board an elektrichka to Dubna.

With regards of route planning, install Yandex.Maps and 2GIS on your phone and cross-verify what they tell you.